# Laravel : How create new array from two arrays with deferent length

Tags: arrays, laravel

I have two arrays with different lengths in a controller like the following.

```
$absences = Absence::query()
    ->select('name')
    ->selectRaw('count(name) as counts')
    ->whereBetween('date', [$req->from, $req->to])
    ->where('stage', $req->stage)
    ->where('group', $req->group)
    ->where('subject', $req->subject)
    ->where('vacs', 'No')
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->get();

$vacs = Absence::query()
    ->select('name')
    ->selectRaw('count(name) as counts')
    ->whereBetween('date', [$req->from, $req->to])
    ->where('stage', $req->stage)
    ->where('group', $req->group)
    ->where('subject', $req->subject)
    ->where('vacs', 'yes')
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->get();
```

Depending on this I will get two arrays, the outputs will be something like the following.

**Absence output**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Sam",
    "counts": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Tom",
    "counts": 1
  }
]
```

**Vacs output**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Sam",
    "counts": 1
  }
]
```

Now I want to create a new array with this output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Sam",
    "abs_counts": 2,
    "vac_counts": 1,
  },
  {
    "name": "Tom",
    "abs_counts": 1,
    "vac_counts": 0,
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one query:

```
$data = Absence::query()
    ->select('name')
    ->selectRaw("name, sum(if(vacs = 'No', 1, 0)) as abs_counts, sum(if(vacs = 'yes', 1, 0)) as vac_counts")
    ->whereBetween('date', [$req->from, $req->to])
    ->where('stage', $req->stage)
    ->where('group', $req->group)
    ->where('subject', $req->subject)
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->get();
```

Comment: thanks alot it is corect